# Create/Delete fail due to cached ID?

Tags: mysql, go, visual-studio-code, go-gorm

I have the following code (set up for Go unit testing) in Visual Studio Code (VSCode). It basically consists of 4 unit tests:

1. TestGormCreateDB: Re-create MySQL database users table
2. TestCreateMoon: Add user "Moon" record to users table
3. TestCreateDaltrey: Add user "Daltrey" to users table
4. TestDeleteDaltrey: Delete user "Daltrey" from users table

If you have MySQL you can run this in VSCode by replacing mySQLHost, mySQLUser, mySQLPass and mySQLDBName with your values (Have to create an empty database in MySQL first). Then in VSCode, you can manually run TestGormCreateDB, TestCreateMoon, TestCreateDaltrey, TestDeleteDaltrey, TestCreateDaltrey, TestDeleteDaltrey etc...

Every time a Daltrey entry is deleted and then re-created, the MySQL auto incremented ID increases by 1. Eventually, either TestCreateDaltrey or TestDeleteDaltrey, while not reporting an error, will not update the database (at times TestCreateDaltrey will fail to add new record, and other times TestDeleteDaltrey will not delete the existing record it should). This is because at some point the ID in the GORM modeled User{} struct takes on a previous ID from a previous Create or Delete, as if ID has been cached, and ID in the User{} struct starts using an invalid ID (the record in the users table has ID 4, but the code finds Daltrey as having ID 3). I cannot tell if this is my bug, a VSCode Unit Test bug (User struct is cached from the running of one unit test to another), a GORM cache bug, or even a MySQL cache bug.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "testing"

    // MySQL db driver. Aliased to blank identifier, because we need the init()
    //   function to run, but we are not using anything else in the driver.
    // _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"

    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
)

const (
    mySQLHost    = "localhost" // Replace with your MySQL host.
    mySQLPort    = "3306"
    mySQLUser    = "mysqluser" // Enter MySQL user.
    mySQLPass    = "mysqlpass" // Enter MySQL password.
    mySQLDBName  = "mysqldb"   // Enter MySQL database name.
    mySQLCharset = "utf8mb4"   // See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name  string `gorm:"not null"`
    Email string `gorm:"unique_index; not null"`
}

// Db provides global access to the database.
var db *gorm.DB

func init() {
    var err error
    db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", getDSN())
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to connect to database", mySQLDBName)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = db.DB().Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to ping database", mySQLDBName)
    }
    fmt.Println("successfully connected to database")
    return
}

func getDSN() string {
    dsn := mySQLUser + ":" + mySQLPass
    dsn += "@tcp(" + mySQLHost + ":" + mySQLPort + ")"
    dsn += "/" + mySQLDBName
    dsn += "?charset=" + mySQLCharset
    dsn += "&parseTime=True"
    dsn += "&loc=Local"
    return dsn
}

// String to satisfy the Stringer interface.
func (u User) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("user: ID=%d Name=%s Email=%s", u.ID, u.Name, u.Email)
}

// NewUser creates a new user struct, not adding user to database.
func NewUser(name, email string) User {
    return User{Name: name, Email: email}
}

// NewDatabaseUser creates a new user in the database.
func NewDatabaseUser(name, email string) (user User, err error) {
    // Create a user.
    user = NewUser(name, email)
    fmt.Println("NewDatabaseUser (before Create):", user)
    // Create new user in the database.
    err = user.Create()
    fmt.Println("NewDatabaseUser (after Create):", user)
    if err != nil {
        return User{}, err
    }
    return user, nil
}

// Create a new user, save user info into the database
func (u *User) Create() (err error) {
    err = db.Debug().Create(&u).Error
    fmt.Println("Create:", u)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

// UserByEmail gets a single user given the email
func UserByEmail(email string) (u User, err error) {
    err = db.Debug().Where("email = ?", email).First(&u).Error
    fmt.Println("UserByEmail:", u)
    if err != nil {
        return User{}, err
    }
    return u, nil
}

// Delete user from database
func (u *User) Delete() (err error) {
    delUser, err := UserByEmail(u.Email)
    fmt.Println("Delete delUser: ", delUser)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Double check that user has primary key ID.  If primary key is 0,
    //   GORM will delete all users from the database!
    if delUser.ID <= 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("attempt to delete user with invalid id %d", delUser.ID)
    }
    err = db.Debug().Unscoped().Delete(&delUser).Error
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func TestGormCreateDB(t *testing.T) {
    // Cleanup old stuff.
    if err := db.Debug().DropTableIfExists("users").Error; err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Create new stuff.
    if err := db.Debug().CreateTable(&User{}).Error; err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func TestCreateMoon(t *testing.T) {
    // Create new user in the database.
    u, err := NewDatabaseUser("Keith Moon", "keith.moon@who.com")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("created", u)
    }
}

func TestCreateDaltrey(t *testing.T) {
    // Create new user in the database.
    u, err := NewDatabaseUser("Roger Daltrey", "roger.daltrey@who.com")
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("created", u)
    }
}

func TestDeleteDaltrey(t *testing.T) {
    u := User{Email: "roger.daltrey@who.com"}
    fmt.Println("TestDeleteUser:", u)
    err := u.Delete()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("delete user with email %s failed: %v\n", u.Email, err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("user with email %s deleted\n", u.Email)
}
```

Comment: Can you please summarize what is the problem? and what you have tried?

Comment: TestCreateDaltrey adds record to the users table in the database, assigns an auto incremented ID (the primary key) to that record. TestDeleteDaltrey is run, searches for record with matching email address. Record that comes back populates the User{} variable u, whose u.ID value should match ID of record just added.  But it does not, the u.ID that comes back is the ID of a previously added and deleted record. What this means is that the line `err = db.Debug().Where("email = ?", email).First(&u)` in the method UserByEmail() appears to be returning a User{} record with a stale or cached ID.

Comment: In VSCode unit tests have the following link above them: `run test | debug test`. When you select `run test`, it runs the test and I see the failure.  But I have never seen the failure when using `debug test`. Which means I cannot debug thru the GORM code. Which leads me to believe VSCode unit test infrastructure is somehow caching variable data.

Comment: BTW - MySQL version is `mysql  Ver 8.0.19 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)`. Go version is `go version go1.12 darwin/amd64` running on MacOS Mojave.  VSCode is 1.42.1.

Comment: Another observation: I run wireshark to trace network packets (by IP address and MySQL tcp port 3306), because the Mac and MySQL database are on different machines.  When failure occurs there are no packets coming from the Mac. So for example, I run TestCreateDaltrey, and get the following output:

Comment: === RUN   TestCreateDaltrey
successfully connected to database
NewDatabaseUser (before Create): user: ID=0 Name=Roger Daltrey Email=roger.daltrey@who.com

Comment: [35m(/Users/crizzo/go/src/github.com/techsavvyme/gorm/main_test.go:89)[0m 
[33m[2020-02-23 13:04:23][0m  [36;1m[2.33ms][0m  INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`,`updated_at`,`deleted_at`,`name`,`email`) VALUES ('2020-02-23 13:04:23','2020-02-23 13:04:23',NULL,'Roger Daltrey','roger.daltrey@who.com')  
[36;31m[1 rows affected or returned ][0m

Comment: Create: user: ID=2 Name=Roger Daltrey Email=roger.daltrey@who.com
NewDatabaseUser (after Create): user: ID=2 Name=Roger Daltrey Email=roger.daltrey@who.com
created user: ID=2 Name=Roger Daltrey Email=roger.daltrey@who.com
--- PASS: TestCreateDaltrey (0.02s)
PASS
ok   github.com/techsavvyme/gorm (cached)
Success: Tests passed.

Comment: Which implies new daltrey recrod with ID=2 was created in the MySQL database.  But no record has been added and there are no packets shown in Wireshark. So bottom line is VSCode or GORM appear to not be sending the MySQL requests over the network to the database, either on a create or on a delete.

Comment: The last test implies GORM is somehow getting and processing the request, but not sending the MySQL request over the network to the database, either on a create or on a delete?  I don't know how it could generate a dynamic ID without communicating with the database.

Comment: Yes, whenever I select `run test` in VSCode, it is hit or miss whether I am going to see mysql packets over the network in Wireshark.  When there are no packets, the tests fail.  Whenever I select `debug test` in VSCode, the packets are always sent, and there is no failure. So something different is happening when `run test` is selected.